# Write a function to return all the keys present in an object at any level

Tags: javascript, object

I need to write a function that lists all keys in an object at any level

Input

```
{ 
    a: 5,
    b: { 
        c: { 
            d: 10 
        } 
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```js
var object = { a:5,b:{c:{d:10} }}; 
var x = Object.keys(object);
for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    if(typeof(object[x[i]]) === "object")
    {
        var y = Object.keys(object[x[i]]);
        console.log(y);//## Heading ##
    }
}
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ObjectKeys</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <p id="demo3"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use a recursive function to iterate through the object, adding the keys of the object at the current level to an array, something like this:

```js
var object = {
  a: 5,
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 10
    }
  }
};

function getKeys(obj, arr) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    arr.push(key);
    arr = getKeys(obj[key], arr);
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(getKeys(object, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive function that will itterete over your object keys and will add them to an array and look under them as well for more keys.

something like:

```js
function getKeysOf(o) {
  if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') return [];
  return Object.keys(o)
    .reduce((keys, key) => {
     keys.push(key);
     const subKeys = getKeysOf(o[key])
     if (subKeys.length) {
      keys.push(...subKeys);
      }
     return keys;
}, [])}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using [`replacer function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
let obj =  { a: 5, b: { c: { d: 10 } }}

let getKeys = (obj) =>{
  let arr = []
  JSON.stringify(obj,(key,value)=>{
    arr.push(key)
    return value
  })
  return arr.slice(1)
}

console.log(getKeys(obj))
```

**Why we need `slice(1)` here ?**

> Initially, the replacer function is called with an empty string as key
>   representing the object being stringified.